# Use of rank() function in BUGS

Tags: winbugs

If I run the following code in OpenBUGS:

```
MODEL
{
for (i in 1:50) {
variable[i] ~ dunif(50, 100)
}
item <- rank(variable[], 1)
}
```

I expect `item` to be 0, as there are no components of `variable` that can be below 1. This is based on the definition of the function `rank` from the OpenBUGS user manual:

"`rank(v, s)`:  number of components of `v` less than or equal to `s`"

However, the posterior for `item` is actually:

```
        mean    sd      MC_error    val2.5pc    median  val97.5pc   start   sample
item    25.4    14.39   0.4072      1.0         25.0    49.0        1       1000
```

Meaning that around 25 components of `variable` are less than or equal to 1, when clearly none of the components of `variable` can be less than 1--confirmed by the posterior distribution of `variable` values:

```
                mean    sd          MC_error    val2.5pc    median  val97.5pc   start   sample
variable[1]     74.27   14.06       0.4417      51.51       73.73   98.96       1001    1000
variable[2]     74.32   14.29       0.5154      51.43       74.02   98.52       1001    1000
variable[3]     75.1    14.53       0.5623      51.34       75.2    99.07       1001    1000
variable[4]     75.78   14.41       0.3846      51.22       76.44   98.77       1001    1000
variable[5]     74.97   14.93       0.5557      51.24       74.8    99.18       1001    1000
variable[6]     75.13   14.61       0.4657      51.1        75.17   99.05       1001    1000
variable[7]     74.65   14.39       0.4296      51.58       74.44   98.57       1001    1000
variable[8]     75.01   14.28       0.4517      51.23       75.05   98.72       1001    1000
variable[9]     75.2    14.04       0.4309      52.09       74.83   98.7        1001    1000
variable[10]    75.3    14.47       0.4811      51.31       75.55   98.96       1001    1000
variable[11]    74.85   14.39       0.5504      51.55       74.65   98.7        1001    1000
variable[12]    74.85   14.42       0.4884      51.56       74.57   98.34       1001    1000
variable[13]    75.54   14.91       0.4995      50.95       76.14   98.97       1001    1000
variable[14]    75.43   14.46       0.4723      51.56       75.39   98.83       1001    1000
variable[15]    74.97   14.39       0.4658      51.14       75.58   98.74       1001    1000
variable[16]    75.39   14.46       0.5693      51.44       76.24   98.53       1001    1000
variable[17]    74.41   14.67       0.4356      51.03       73.34   98.78       1001    1000
variable[18]    75.09   14.22       0.3771      51.49       74.99   98.81       1001    1000
variable[19]    75.7    14.31       0.394       51.46       76.02   98.55       1001    1000
variable[20]    74.8    14.23       0.5463      51.64       75.12   98.86       1001    1000
variable[21]    74.83   14.56       0.4997      51.2        74.74   98.65       1001    1000
variable[22]    75.58   14.38       0.4412      51.38       76.6    98.3        1001    1000
variable[23]    74.64   14.42       0.4406      51.34       74.05   98.37       1001    1000
variable[24]    74.85   14.09       0.5247      51.6        74.72   98.96       1001    1000
variable[25]    75.48   14.39       0.4642      51.14       76.12   98.69       1001    1000
variable[26]    75.26   14.57       0.5391      51.18       75.07   98.92       1001    1000
variable[27]    74.49   14.5        0.4723      51.39       74.51   98.78       1001    1000
variable[28]    75.37   14.47       0.3562      51.09       75.5    98.64       1001    1000
variable[29]    74.64   14.37       0.4637      51.25       74.57   98.64       1001    1000
variable[30]    74.66   14.88       0.5224      51.1        74.73   98.83       1001    1000
variable[31]    75.48   14.31       0.4403      51.84       75.83   99.08       1001    1000
variable[32]    74.74   14.43       0.5379      51.1        74.07   99.13       1001    1000
variable[33]    74.67   14.33       0.4465      50.98       74.11   98.72       1001    1000
variable[34]    74.43   14.64       0.5293      51.05       73.72   99.05       1001    1000
variable[35]    74.51   14.44       0.4683      51.39       73.99   98.6        1001    1000
variable[36]    75.44   14.42       0.438       51.59       75.71   99.08       1001    1000
variable[37]    74.8    14.27       0.495       51.21       75.03   98.87       1001    1000
variable[38]    74.97   14.24       0.4463      52.05       75.64   98.73       1001    1000
variable[39]    74.82   14.67       0.5232      51.32       74.92   98.96       1001    1000
variable[40]    74.81   14.37       0.4862      51.3        74.58   98.79       1001    1000
variable[41]    74.77   14.51       0.3887      51.18       74.74   98.47       1001    1000
variable[42]    74.72   14.62       0.4296      51.35       74.37   98.66       1001    1000
variable[43]    75.18   14.12       0.4195      51.43       75.35   97.86       1001    1000
variable[44]    75.88   13.7        0.4136      51.86       76.14   99.0        1001    1000
variable[45]    74.6    14.2        0.3913      51.14       73.98   98.52       1001    1000
variable[46]    75.84   14.34       0.434       51.62       75.66   98.92       1001    1000
variable[47]    75.1    14.87       0.4791      51.13       75.11   99.07       1001    1000
variable[48]    75.06   14.14       0.4707      51.14       74.68   98.78       1001    1000
variable[49]    74.75   14.6        0.4521      51.3        74.4    98.93       1001    1000
variable[50]    75.2    14.36       0.4878      51.3        75.33   98.51       1001    1000
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Andrew Millard, via the [BUGS] listserv:

The OpenBugs manual gives the definition as

`rank(v, s)`     number of components of v less than or equal to s

which is what I had based my code on, but the manual is wrong and it should be

`rank(v, s)`    number of components of v less than or equal to the s-th component of v

Answer (score 0):

`rank(u[],i)` returns the rank of the ith element of u.

Since all of your "variable" nodes are equivalent distributions, the rank() function will return a value that is (basically) 1/2 of the number of elements you have in the for loop (or 25 in your example).

`item <- rank(variable[], 1)` will give 25 (mean)
`item <- rank(variable[], 10)` will give 25 (mean)
`item <- rank(variable[], 55)` will give an error during sampling.